# How to use Facebook places SDK in Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

The Facebook places SDK is only available in Objective-C, I am not to good with understanding OBJC and all the documentation on how to use this library is in OBJC. I pod installed the library using cocoa pods.

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit'
```

my Podfile uses framework so I don't think I would be needing a header file.

```
[self.placesManager
 generatePlacesGraphRequestForSearchTerm:@"pizza"
 categories: @[@"FOOD_BEVERAGE"]
 fields: @[FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyName,
           FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyAbout,
           FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyPlaceID]
 distance:1000
 cursor:nil // Pagination cursor
 completion:^(FBSDKGraphRequest * _Nullable graphRequest, CLLocation * _Nullable location, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     if (graphRequest) {
         [graphRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             // Handle the response.
             // The result will contain the JSON for the place search.
         }];
     }
 }];
```

and

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *graphRequest = [self.placesManager
                                   placesGraphRequestForLocation:nil
                                   searchTerm:@"pizza"
                                   categories: @[@"FOOD_BEVERAGE"]
                                   fields: @[FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyName,
                                             FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyAbout,
                                             FBSDKPlacesFieldKeyPlaceID]
                                   distance:1000
                                   cursor:nil];
[graphRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Handle the response.
    // The result will contain the JSON for the place search.
}];
```

can someone please convert this to Swift, or tell me how to use this in Swift?